# Use other Bootsrap (4) class when max-width media query hit

Tags: html, css, media-queries, bootstrap-4

I want to use a predefined class, from Bootstrap 4, in my custom CSS (override) as soon as the screen max-width hits 600px.
Is this possible in my CSS file? Or is it possible to change the class in the HTML code?

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center my-4">
```

The 'my-4' gives the top and bottom margin additionally more spacing, I want to change this class to 'my-2', so the margin spacing is less. [More info about the Bootstrap spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Thank you already. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the class name from my-4 to my-2 is not a good choice. Use css Media queries to change the css.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this method, but there has to be a way. The choice is better in my opinion because they're predefined and responsive (known from Bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for CSS @media annotation,
This may be useful: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Yes, I use the media queries as well, but that is not what I wanted. I wonder if I can change the class in the HTML code as soon as the max-width hits a certain value.. I'm guessing it has to be done by js